# jquery add one class to two elements on scroll but with different properties

Tags: jquery, css

My scroll function works it adds the class `.scroll` but in my CSS I have this:

```
.scroll #directory-search{
position: fixed !important;
top: 0 !important;
left: 0 !important;
z-index: 10;
width: 100%;
}
```

and

```
.scroll #main{
padding-top: 70px;
}
```

1# makes the menu bar stay fixed so it scrolls and stays on the top on a certain point.

2# gives the content a padding because it misses 70 px because of the menu bar.

Here is my jQuery:

```
/*sticky menu bar*/
var pos;
var amount;
    var elem = $('#directory-search').first();
    pos = $(elem).offset().top;


function scroll() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > pos) {
        $('#directory-search, #main').addClass('scroll');
    } else {
        $('#directory-search, #main').removeClass('scroll');
    }
};



$(window).scroll(scroll);
var scroll = function (section) {

};
```

It works fine. It adds the class `.scroll` to both `#main` and `#directory-search`.

But what I really want is that the CSS class `.scroll #directory-search` is gonna be added to the `#directory-search`
and the CSS class `.scroll #main` is going to be added to the `#main`.

I had another script before. It did work but they wanted me to shorten the code and they said you have to do it like this but I can't get it to work.

Comment: what's your shorten code??? which is not working...

Comment: this is my shorten code :)

Comment: I think its my css because it adds the class scroll to the #directory-search and #main but it doesnt find the css code f i make a class in css just called .scroll{ and add code here } it does work but than both #main and #directory-search get the same property.

Comment: I think you are trying this: `$('#directory-search, #main').parent().addClass('scroll');`

Comment: Mr_green no I want it get added to the two elements not the the parent.

Comment: @Rikato try it once and tell me..

Comment: @Mr_Green since OP's selector is wrong parent() method is no sense to use....

Comment: @C-link actually keeping `parent()` should work but also removing space from class also works. I added below as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the space between the classes in css.

```
.scroll#directory-search
```

and

```
.scroll#main
```

Comment: @Rikato it's because you have the class in that element. With space you are targeting a nested div. clear???